# Which fallacy is this?

Tags: probability, percentages

Assume that all people are either right-handed or left-handed, and likewise either right-footed or left-footed. 90% of people are right-handed. 90% of right-handed people are right-footed, but only 50% of left-handed people are left-footed as well. Which is more common: left-handedness or left-footedness?

STOP here, and have a go at answering that question first before continuing.

And then read on:

The answer is easy enough to get if you calculate it. Yet it feels counter-intuitive. Two people I tested this on (another used maths and got it right) assumed that because right-footedness is so dominant among right-handers and common among left-handers, that right-footedness should be even more common than right-handedness. There's some sort of fallacy at work here: any idea of what it is?

Comment: The fallacy is that people tend to directly compare percentages with one another even though quite often (as is the case here) that percentages are taken of different quantities and thus cannot be compared.

Answer (score 3):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosecutor's_fallacy

People will see that half of the the left handed people are left footed and assume that left handed people are more common, but they don't realize that a small set of a large population can be comparable to a large set of a small population.

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that what you're assuming about handedness is a false dichotomy. Since some people are ambidextrous.

There's nothing wrong with the statement above as it is written as a statement about folks in general. You may want to rule out ambidextrous people as outliers (they're very rare).

You're really just saying that people who are left handed aren't left footed as frequently. So if you looked at left and right footed folks and compared that to handedness, you'd see "rightfootedness" outnumbers that of the left.

Comment: In practice, yes, it's more complicated than that. I know someone who's left-handed but plays guitar right-handed. I think that the figures that I took from Wikipedia are pretty accurate if you abide by the assumptions in the question, which ask the reader to ignore ambidexterity.